# .htaccess rule not working

Tags: rewrite

This is my .htaccess code ... the first condition is working and the other one is not

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    ^([\w-]+)/?$    Page.php?PageID=$1    [L]    # Process parrots
RewriteRule    ^([\w-]+)/?$    Product.php?ProductID=$1    [L]    # Process parrots
ErrorDocument 404 /ChicDemure/404.php
```

Comment: Please add your question to the body, not only the title. Explain what you want to happen, what you're doing and what is wrong with what happens now.

Comment: The rules are identical. How is apache supposed to distinguish between them?

Answer (score 1):

The expressions in your rules are identical. Since apache can't know which one it should use it uses the first one that matches.

You have to make them distinguishable, for example like this:

```
RewriteRule    ^page/([\w-]+)/?$    Page.php?PageID=$1    [L]
RewriteRule    ^product/([\w-]+)/?$    Product.php?ProductID=$1    [L]
```

Of course you have to change the links accordingly.